# Regex to replace custom "variables" in PHP

Tags: php, regex

does anyone know how to do a regex which works with preg_replace for the following?

I have a string like the following:

```
$string = "Best event in town is: [LOC=LONDON]Party London[/LOC] (more text...) [LOC=PARIS]Paris Party[/LOC] Check it out!";
```

and I have a location:

```
$location = "LONDON"
```

Now I need to replace the text between [LOC=*] and [/LOC] with a custom text for the current location $location and remove all which doesn't match the current location. Text between the square brackets should not be removed.

In the example above the result should look like:

```
  Best event in town is: Party London (more text...) Check it out!
```

Do you have any idea how to do it with preg_match or do you know any other efficient way?

Thanks in advance!
Tobias

Comment: what is $location variable doing here ... ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your attempt.

Comment: The $location variable has the value of the location where the text should not be removed. In this example the $location is "LONDON" so it should look for texts between [LOC=LONDON] and [/LOC] and keep the text between the square brackets. As there is also [LOC=PARIS] and $location is not "PARIS" everything between and including [LOC=PARIS] [/LOC] needs to be removed.

Comment: My plan is to check the whole string through prep_replace for [LOC=x1] x2 [/LOC], then loop though the array and check if $x1 is $location. If it is, replace the whole string with x2 and if its not, replace it with an empty string. But I don't know how to do a regex for that. The regex needs to provide x1, x2 and x for the whole string (including the square brackets, to remove it from $string)

Comment: put your last comment in the end of your question, as an indication of your attempt. and also have a look in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\[(?=LOC=LONDON)[^\]]*?\]([^[]*)\[\/LOC\]|\[LOC[^]]*\][^\[]*\[\/LOC\]
```

and replace by:

```
\1
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GDKBje/1/)

Sample Source ( [Run Here](http://ideone.com/dFOB9q) ) :

```
$location="LONDON";
$re = '/\[(?=LOC='.$location.')[^\]]*?\]([^[]*)\[\/LOC\]|\[LOC[^]]*\][^\[]*\[\/LOC\]/';
$str = 'Best event in town is: [LOC=LONDON]Party London[/LOC] (more text...) [LOC=PARIS]Paris Party[/LOC] Check it out! [LOC=DHAKA]dHAKA Party[/LOC] Check it out! ';
$subst = '\\1';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The most versatile solution uses [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string = "Best event in town is: [LOC=LONDON]Party London[/LOC] (more text...) [LOC=PARIS]Paris Party[/LOC] Check it out!";
$location = 'LONDON';

$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '#\[LOC=([^\]]*)\](.*?)\[/LOC\]#',
    function (array $matches) use ($location) {
        if ($matches[1] === $location) {
            return $matches[2];
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    $string
);
```

The `regex` matches one `[LOC][/LOC]` block and captures the value of `LOC` and the content of the block:

```
\[               # matches the "[" character (unescaped, it is a meta-character)
    LOC=         # matches the string "LOC=" (there is nothing special about it)
    (            # start of the first capturing group (doesn't match anything)
        [^\]]*   # matches any character except `]`, zero or more times (`*`)
    )            # end of the first capturing group (doesn't match anything)
]                # matches the "]" character itself (it doesn't need to be 
                 # escaped when used outside of a character class)
(                # start of the second capturing group
     .*?         # matches any character, any number of times, not greedy (`?`)
)                # end of the second capturing group
\[/LOC\]         # matches the string "[/LOC]"
```

When a match is found, `preg_replace_callback()` invokes the given callback function with one argument of type `array` that contains at index `0` the part of the string that matched the `regex` (f.e. `[LOC=LONDON]Party London[/LOC]`) and at numeric indices starting with `1` the fragments of string that match the corresponding capturing groups, if any.

For the input string, when the callback is invoked for the first time, `print_r($matches)` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [LOC=LONDON]Party London[/LOC]
    [1] => LONDON
    [2] => Party London
)
```

The callback's code doesn't need much explanation. If `$matches[1]` (the string between `[LOC=` and `]` is the same as `$location` then replace the matched string with `$matches[2]` (the string between `[LOC=...]` and `[/LOC]`), otherwise replace it with the empty string (to remove the `[LOC][/LOC]` block and its content).

Answer (score 1):

```
function stringInject(str, arr) {
    if (typeof str !== 'string' || !(arr instanceof Array)) {
        return false;
    }

    return str.replace(/({\d})/g, function(i) {
        return arr[i.replace(/{/, '').replace(/}/, '')];
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
var oldString = "Best party in town is in {0}. Not in {1}";
var newString = stringInject(oldString, ["London", "Paris"]);

// Best party in town is in London. Not in Paris.
```

**GitHub**

https://github.com/tjcafferkey/stringinject

**NPM**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject